Windows 11 cannot see NVME drive after major update but Linux can
A few days ago I tried to update my Windows 11 PC to the new W11 major update (24H2 if I'm not mistaken). After a reboot, my PC was unable to boot into Windows because Windows cannot recognize the NVME drive it's installed on anymore.
When it tries to boot, it shows a loading animation (spinner) for an unusually long time (like 1 minute+) and goes into Windows rescue/recovery mode. The only thing I was able to do there was to go into command prompt and check the drives. All my drives are there but not a NVME (boot).
Looks like a dead NVME? So I thought.
As a last resort, I tried to boot Ubuntu from USB stick and discovered that my NVME drive is... fine? I can mount it, I can read all the files from NTFS or do a backup just in case. I have also checked its health/smart information but nothing shows any sign of failure.
I played with all settings related to SSD in the BIOS I could find, but to no avail. I could not find any settings directly related to NVME in my MSI b450 VDH MAX motherboard BIOS. Of course, I have tried Googling similar issues but I could not find similar problems.
Any suggestions what I can do next?

What model of NVMe are you using? Perhaps you have been affected by Critical Update for Western Digital and SanDisk Internal SSDs That Can Cause BSOD on Windows 11 24H2

It's Samsung 970 EVO Plus 2TB.

+1 for clearly stating issue and performing preliminary test with another OS. Hope you get a workaround, other than reverting from that update.

It may be worth creating the Windows 11 install media on a USB stick and seeing if boot from the install media, selecting to repair the PC, and opening a command window can see the files on the NVMe. I have one dual booting PC in which Windows 11 never boots from the NVMe after attempting to update to 24H2, get a IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL stop code after a few seconds of the spinner. The Windows 11 24H2 – 10.0.26100.2033 on USB media fails to boot in the same way (media OK on a different type of PC). Perhaps 24H2 has introduced some bug which fails on certain hardware, am trying to investigate.

Are you sure it was ONLY Windows 24H2 update? Windows Update can do BIOS updates, too, maybe UEFI settings got changed? I know you checked the settings, but from my own experience it's easy to overlook simplest settings like boot not set to UEFI with Secure Boot...

I have finally found the solution!
I had to update the BIOS to the newest beta version (started from 7A38vBG) in order to boot Windows. First I updated to the newest stable version (7A38vBM) but that did nothing (I was still thrown into recovery mode without NVMe being recognized). Then I tried the newest firmware but beta version instead (7A38vBN2) and at first it looked like the result was the same, but I did notice some fluctuations in fan speeds which meant that SOMETHING was being processed and that meant that it had to come from SOMEWHERE (boot drive). After a few minutes of waiting on the spinner screen (probably the update was reverted at this point), I was shown the Windows login screen.
So, yeah, 20+ years of experience with computers and I never had thought that I would need to update BIOS firmware in order to boot the OS that was previously working. Thanks for the help!
